# Traversing polymorphic structures and performing a transformation only in few cases

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, scrap-your-boilerplate

Suppose we represent a company hierarchy in the following way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}

import           Data.Data
import           Data.Generics.Aliases
import           Data.Generics.Schemes

data CompanyAsset = Employee Name Salary
                  | Plant Name
                  | Boss Name Performance Salary [CompanyAsset]
                  | Pet Name
                  | Car Id
                  | Guild [CompanyAsset]
                  | Fork CompanyAsset CompanyAsset
                  -- ... and imagine 100 more options that recursively use `CompanyAsset`.
                  deriving (Show, Data)

-- Performance of the department.
data Performance = Good | Bad deriving (Show, Data)

type Name = String

type Id = Int

newtype Salary = Salary Double deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

raise :: Salary -> Salary
```

And I would like to defne a function that raises the salaries of company assets that do not have a `Boss` ancestor whose department had a `Bad` performance. Such a function can be easily defined as follows:

```
raiseSalaries :: CompanyAsset -> CompanyAsset
raiseSalaries (Boss n Good s as) = Boss n Good (raise s) (raiseSalaries <$> as)
raiseSalaries a@(Boss _ Bad _ _) = a -- The salaries of everything below are not raised if the performance is 'Bad'
raiseSalaries ... -- and from here onwards we have **boilerplate**!
```

The problem is that this requires a lot of boilerplate (for the sake of the discussion, please assume that the `CompanyAsset` is given and cannot be changed).

So my question is whether there is a way of traversing data structures in such a way that the boilerplate above can be avoided.

This question is related to a [similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/81542618?noredirect=1) I posted, but in this case the use of [`everywhere'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.7/docs/Data-Generics-Schemes.html#v:everywhere-39-) won't help, since there are cases in which salaries should not be raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished with a [`Traversal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Type.html#t:Traversal) for `CompanyAsset`. You can write it yourself, or use [`uniplate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Data-Data-Lens.html#v:uniplate) or [`plate`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:plate) from lens.

For illustration, I'm going to write a traversal for `CompanyAsset` explicitly. It applies an operation (which I call `p` as in `pure`) to each direct descendant of a company asset. Note that `traverse_ca pure == pure`.

```
traverse_ca :: Applicative f => (CompanyAsset -> f CompanyAsset) -> CompanyAsset -> f CompanyAsset
traverse_ca p ca =
  case ca of
    Fork ca1 ca2      -> Fork <$> p ca1 <*> p ca2
    Boss n perf s cas -> Boss n perf s <$> traverse p cas
    Guild cas         -> Guild <$> traverse p cas
    otherwise         -> pure ca
```

By itself this is enough to define `raiseSalaries` without any additional boilerplate.

```
import Data.Functor.Identity

raiseSalaries :: CompanyAsset -> CompanyAsset
raiseSalaries (Boss n Good s as) = Boss n Good (raise s) (raiseSalaries <$> as)
raiseSalaries a@(Boss _ Bad _ _) = a -- The salaries of everything below are not raised if the performance is 'Bad'
raiseSalaries a = runIdentity $ traverse_ca (pure . raiseSalaries) a
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution which uses [recursion-schemes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes), and also [a bit of Template Haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable-TH.html#v:makeBaseFunctor) to generate a base `CompanyAssetF` functor:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable (cata,embed)
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH (makeBaseFunctor)

$(makeBaseFunctor ''CompanyAsset)

raiseSalaries :: CompanyAsset -> CompanyAsset
raiseSalaries asset = cata go asset raise'
    where
    go c raiser = embed $
        case c of
            BossF _ Bad _ _ -> fmap ($ id) c
            _ -> raiser $ fmap ($ raiser) c
    raise' (BossF name perf salary rec) = BossF name perf (raise salary) rec
    raise' (EmployeeF name salary) = EmployeeF name (raise salary)
    raise' other = other
```

The algebra returns a function in order to enable the "should get raise" information to flow from the root to the leaves.